# What is the solution to the riddle to access the Conception Cube?

Tags: remember-me

Episode seven of Remember Me has you fight your way through swarms of leapers inside Mnemopolis Tower until you reach a hall with the words `HOMINIS M3MORIZE EVOLUTIO` on the wall as per below;

[image]

It appears possible to interact with each of the individual letters visible in the screenshot so this is probably some kind of word puzzle. Captain Trace's remembrance is another riddle as follows:

> May Memorize's error fall as mankind holds its head up high and evolution's end looks down upon all that has gone before - only then will the secret be unmasked.

What is the solution to the riddle to access the Conception Cube?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May Memorize's error fall...

**HINT :**

> "The error" refers to one of the letters

**SOLUTION:**

> The error is the '3', so move that downwards (fall)

---

...as mankind holds its head up high...

**HINT :**

> 'Hominis' is latin for 'human'

**SOLUTION:**

> The 'head' of 'Hominis' is the first letter.  So move it up.

---

...and evolution's end looks down upon all that has gone before.

**HINT :**

> "evolution's end" refers to one of the letters

**SOLUTION:**

> Move the 'o' in 'evolutio' up *(because it's "looking down" on the other letters)*

Comment: Wow, thanks for the solution (or better the explanation). Found the solution really easy with Google, but didn't understand it. Now I know, the reason is a horrible German translation. It has nothing to do with the Puzzle!

Answer (score -1):

Move the h in hominis up , the 3 in m3morize down and the last letter of evolutio up. For the second riddle shoot wife 2 times , husband 3 and child 5.